# How to get the Text of a Div Class and Place inside a Label?

Tags: html, vb.net, class

I'm trying to get the "valor" that is inside the site div from [Poloniex](https://poloniex.com/exchange#usdt_btc) to put inside a Label every 1 second using Timer after load site completely.

**My Completely Code:**

https://pastebin.com/QrcuWnxf

**Div:**

```
<div class="info">valor</div>
```

**I have found that on the page there are several "info" classes...**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**This code worked, but it brought another result than expected ...**

```
    Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection
    theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Div")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        If curElement.OuterHtml.Contains("info") Then
            Variable1 = (curElement.GetAttribute("InnerText"))
        End If
    Next

Label1.Text = Variable1
```

**The result was the value of this Div that also has the "info" class.**

```
<div class="msg"><div class="info">OMG/BTC and OMG/ETH  OmiseGO markets added</div>
```

Comment: Don't work with VB, but can you not assign an id rather than class? I mean you attempted to get the element by ID but entered a class. Sorry if this doesn't apply to VB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second try:

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
  If Element.GetAttribute("className") = "lastPrice" Then
   For Each Element1 As HtmlElement In Element.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        If Element1.GetAttribute("className") = "info" Then
            Dim Variable1 as String = Element1.InnerText
        End If
    Next
  End If
Next
```

Yes, you have to use `className` for `class` attribute.

This code is verified against the following HTML: This also have more than 1 info class.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="firstPrice">
   <div class="name">First Price</div>
   <div class="info">11650.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="lastPrice">
   <div class="name">Last Price</div>
   <div class="info">11650.00</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be super stylish and functional, but it just doesn't work. I don't understand. See: https://imgur.com/re0DHRB.png

Comment: Can you give me the url or the HTML of your target page to analyze

Comment: I added in the beginning the complete code and the site.

Comment: Add Html used in the example.

Comment: @SérgioWilker : Try changing Sunil's `Dim Variable1 as String = Element1.InnerText` to `Variable1 = Element1.InnerText` instead to match your code (you seem to have already declared that variable elsewhere). In theory his code should work, but we cannot know for sure because we don't know what the rest of the HTML looks like (the part encapsulating the tags you're looking for).

Comment: Also @Sunil, don't forget to stop looping once the element has been found.